# How to call parent controller from ActionLink in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view that is shared across Areas.  This view has (or would like to have) an ActionLink like so:

```
            @Html.ActionLink(model.property1, "ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new
            {
                @id = model.property1,
                @class = "someClass",
                @style = "text-decoration: underline; color: blue; cursor: pointer;"
            })
```

How would you change "ControllerName" to be know the actual Controller that called it?

Comment: Just omit the 3rd parameter ("ControllerName"). If the view your in was generated from SomeController/Index then the link will be SomeController/ActionName

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that worked! Thank you. God now I feel stupid for asking a (what now appears as a) simple question. This ASP.Net MVC is really neat but a lot different that the world of Web Forms.

Comment: And I guarantee after your familiar with it you will never go back

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you submit this as your answer, I want to make sure you get the appropriate credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit the 3rd parameter ("ControllerName"). If the view your in was generated from a method in HomeController then the link will be generated as `/Home/ActionName`.